# Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT)

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hiveql

I am planning to save the spark dataframe into hive tables so i can query them and extract latitude and longitude from them since Spark dataframe aren't iterable.

With pyspark in jupyter i wrote this code to make a spark session:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#readmultiple csv with pyspark
 spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive").enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()

 df = spark.read.csv("Desktop/train/train.csv",header=True);

 Pickup_locations=df.select("pickup_datetime","Pickup_latitude",
                          "Pickup_longitude")

 print(Pickup_locations.count())
```

then i run the hiveql :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytempTable") 
spark.sql("create table hive_table as select * from mytempTable");
```

And i get this  error:

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
 : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Hive support is required to      CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);;
 'CreateTable `hive_table`,    org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, ErrorIfExists
+- Project [id#311, vendor_id#312, pickup_datetime#313,    dropoff_datetime#314, passenger_count#315, pickup_longitude#316,     pickup_latitude#317, dropoff_longitude#318, dropoff_latitude#319,     store_and_fwd_flag#320, trip_duration#321]​
```

​

Comment: Do you control how you run spark? I mean are you able to change the submit-spark command parameters?

Answer (score 7):

I was in this situation before. You need to pass a config parameter to spark-submit command so it considers hive as the catalog implementation for your spark sql.

Here is how spark submit looks like:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive  --class harri_sparkStreaming.com_spark_streaming.App  ./target/com-spark-streaming-2.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The trick is in: `--conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive`

Hope this helps